# View a Webpage as Json

Tags: android, html, json, parsing

How do I use Json viewer extension in chrome to view a webpage in json format? I want to see how data is structured so I can parse data and use for my android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON viewer extension is only highlighting JSON documents, so they are easier to read. You  normally cannot "view a webpage as JSON". What you can do is using the developer tools ("F12") to search for JSON structures and to open the respective documents in your browser. The JSON viewer plugin will make it then easier for you to read these documents.